# Finding a book about the principles or concepts of vi or vim

Tags: learning-resources

I remember reading a book about vi or vim. The book is very short. Instead of focusing on vim commands, it teaches about the concepts or principles about vim. And I remember one of the concepts is something like "use vim first and search for commands that you find yourself need".
Does anyone know what that book is? Really appreciate it if someone can help me find it.

Comment: Maybe https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/ ?

Comment: You might also be interested in this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220118/113195. Its ~3 pages of text were more enlightening to me than the books I’ve read on Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full "use vim first and search for commands that you find yourself need" quote, taken from [Seven habits of effective text editing](https://moolenaar.net/habits.html), by Bram Moolenaar:

> There are **three basic steps**:
>
> 1. While you are editing, keep an eye out for actions you repeat and/or spend quite a bit of time on.
> 2. Find out if there is an editor command that will do this action quicker. Read the documentation, ask a friend, or look at how others do this.
> 3. Train using the command. Do this until your fingers type it without thinking.

Comment: Exactly this one, Seven habits of effective text editing. Though I thought it would be some longer text than this. The text is so concise and so useful. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like: [A Byte of Vim](https://github.com/swaroopch/byte-of-vim) 89 pages

But it could also be: [Mastering Vim Quickly](https://jovicailic.org/mastering-vim-quickly/) 112 pages

The advice: Use Vim and learn what you need is an advice of Bram Moolenaar found in many of his talk. I know it from the Google talk: [7 Habits For Effective Text Editing 2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eX9m3g5J-XA) he gave in 2007

Comment: Yes, seven habits for effective text editing, really good text. Appreciate it and thanks for the link to the associated Google talk.